# How to find what categorical variables explain a continuous dependent variable?

Tags: correlation, categorical-data

I am currently working on a statistical analysis for a project, I have a dependent variable ($y$) that represents delays in days, it's continuous and take integer values.

I also have a set of over 90 features/dimensions/predictors, most of them are categorical by nature and nominal.

**The Problem :**

I am having a hard time to measure how much a categorical variable (dimension) explain the dependent variable (target), for numerical dimensions I would have used something like the pearson's correlation coefficient. But I'm struggling with categorical variables. I only have 140 rows worth of data, the dependent variable is strongly skewed and heteroscedastic.

**What I've tried so far**

First, For some categorical variables I already konw that they do influence the target variable $y$ from business understanding. However I am looking to use a statistical method that would confirm my own intuition.

For a bunch of other variables/predictors, I don't have a clue if they do influence or don't.

Here's what I have tried :

- Using Box plots for each categorical predictor, although some charts do confirm my intuition, I am looking for a more formal method.
- Doing a one way ANOVA, Welch-Anova, and Kruskal-Wallis Test, each of them give quite different results that don't really confirm what I was looking for. The main problem with this is that for each categorical variable, *I have different sample sizes with different variances (and sometimes the difference is quite huge).*
- Point biserial correlation : some of the categorical variables are not binary and have 3-10 possible values sometimes.

I thought about training a random forest regressor than using the Feature Importance plot, however, I only have 140 rows which is very small for ensemble methods (they might overfit very easily).

Any other tests or coefficients or techniques that could help with my situation ?

**Note :** This article suggest to build a classifier for each categorical variable and then using the accuracy of the classifier to assess if a categorical variable is correlated with the target variable, but this doesn't seem right, because if $y$ explains $X$, doesn't mean that $X$ explains $y$ or did I miss something ?